# Sum of number in brainfuck

Tags: brainfuck

I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the sum of 1+2+3+...+k in brainfuck just with the number k at the beginning of the code?

For example is it possible to do 1+2+3 like this:

`+++>` (here the code creates a two add it with the three, create the one and add it)

Because I can do this : `+++>++>+[<<+>>-]<[<+>-]<` but if k=10000 how can I do this ?

Comment: Isn't 1+2+...+k = k * (k + 1) / 2?

Comment: Yes, it is. I figured he explicitly wanted to do it this way, though.

Comment: @IngoBürk I don't want to do k*(*+1)/2 I want to make a recursive programme like "k=10 a=0 while k>0 a=a+k k=k-1 return a" :)

Comment: @Shadock That's not recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple version. Assume we name the first three cells `y`, `temp0` and `x`. Then we can simply use [this](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Wrapping_2) algorithm within a decrementing loop:

```
+++           # Input number (in fisrt cell)
[             # loop while first cell is not 0
 >[-]         # if second cell is null
 <[>>+<+<-]   # copy first cell in second and third and decrease it to 0
 >[<+>-]      # move second cell in first cell
 <-           # decrement input
]             # go to begin of while loop
>>            # the current cell now has the result
```

Note that this only works up to `k = 22` due to the 8-bit limit. To output the number or deal with larger numbers, you'll have to use extra effort.

Comment: @IngoBürg Thank you very much I will try to understand it step by step :D On my interpretor I have a 32-bit limit if I want :)

Comment: @IngoBürg Well It's very hard for me to understand how you made this program can you explain me please?

Comment: Anything in particular? I've pretty much described it: get a number, loop over it, apply the algorithm from the link I posted and decrement the counter in the loop. I'm glad to answer any specific questions you have about it, though.

Comment: Well I just want to know a method to program step by step it, because if i have to do it I will never find the solution by myself ... :/

Comment: But what steps are confusing you in my description? 1) Take an input. 2) Write a loop for that input that decrements it with every iteration. 3) Within the loop, perform a simple addition (for the algorithm, see the link). That's all there is to it and that's pretty much the steps I took.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I want to know ^^ I will try to add a bit of shades in my question :)

Comment: Sure. If I understand what exactly I can do to help you understand it better, I'll give it my best shot.

Answer (score 3):

```
,[[>+>+<<-]>-[<+>-]<]>>.
```

A more concise and efficient algorithm than Ingo's. Uses three "slots"

- |num|: original number; decremented each loop.
- |temp|: copied back into |1| each loop
- |total|:  accumulates values each loop

  ```
  +++          input |num|
  [            while |num| is non-zero
    [>+>+<<-]    copy |num| to |temp| and |results|
    >-[<+>-]     copy |temp-1| back to |num|
    <            reset pointer
  ]
  >>.          output |total|
  ```
- same explanation, but in more detail

  ```
  +++          input |num|
  [            while |num| is non-zero

    [             until |num| is zero
      >+>+          increment |temp| and |total|
      <<            return to |num|
      -             decrement |num|
    ]
    >-           goto |temp|, decrement
    [<+>-]       until |temp| is zero; decrement |temp|; increment |num|

    <           goto |num|
  ]
  >>.          goto |total|, output it
  ```